# Pandas: Apply a function aware of column type to every column of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, types

## Goal

I would like to apply a function that depends on the input column's type to every column in a data frame. Consider the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [["a",1],["b",2]], columns = ["string","num"] )
```

I can test for a column's type:

```
>>> df["num"].dtype            
dtype('int64')
>>> df["num"].dtype in ["int64"]
True
```

And I can apply a function over all columns:

```
>>> df . apply( lambda column: column.sum() )
string    ab
num        3
dtype: object
```

But if I make the function depend on the column's type, I get garbage:

```
>>> df . apply( lambda column:
...             np.nan if not column.dtype in ['float64','float32','int32','int64']
...             else column.sum() )
string   NaN
num      NaN
dtype: float64
```

## Motivation

There are solutions that involve basically dropping the non-numeric columns, but I actually need to retain them. The reason for that is I'm trying to append a row that counts the zeroes in each column to the results of df.describe. Here's an example of a similar function:

```
def describe_plus(df):
  most_stats = df.describe()
  missing_stat = pd.DataFrame( df.isnull().sum()
                             , columns = ["missing"]
                             ).transpose()
  length_stat = pd.DataFrame( [[len(df) for _ in df.columns]]
                            , index = ["length"]
                            , columns = df.columns )
  return length_stat.append( missing_stat.append( most_stats ) )
```

Calling that gives you the ordinary output from pd.describe, plus the length and number missing in each column:

```
>>> describe_plus( df )
              num  string
length   2.000000     2.0
missing  0.000000     0.0
count    2.000000     NaN
mean     1.000000     NaN
std      1.414214     NaN
min      0.000000     NaN
25%      0.500000     NaN
50%      1.000000     NaN
75%      1.500000     NaN
max      2.000000     NaN
```

In addition to length and missing, I would like to add a third row to describe_plus, which counts the number of zeroes in each column, or provides NaN for columns that are not numbers.

## Edit: RafaelC's solution, in this framework

The trick is to discard those non-numeric variables, compute the summary statistics, and then simply append the other statistics (which are defined over every column, even non-numeric ones).

```
def describe_plus_plus(df):
  nums = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
  zeroes = pd.DataFrame( [nums.apply( lambda col: len( col[col==0] ) / 
len(nums) )] )
  return zeroes.append( describe_plus( df ) )
```

Example of it in action:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame( [[0,0,0,""],[0,0,1,"a"],[0,1,2,"b"]], columns = ["none","1/3","2/3","string"] )
>>> describe_plus_plus( df )
              1/3       2/3  none  string
0        0.666667  0.333333   1.0     NaN
length   3.000000  3.000000   3.0     3.0
missing  0.000000  0.000000   0.0     0.0
count    3.000000  3.000000   3.0     NaN
mean     0.333333  1.000000   0.0     NaN
std      0.577350  1.000000   0.0     NaN
min      0.000000  0.000000   0.0     NaN
25%      0.000000  0.500000   0.0     NaN
50%      0.000000  1.000000   0.0     NaN
75%      0.500000  1.500000   0.0     NaN
max      1.000000  2.000000   0.0     NaN
```

Comment: Looking through the source code, the problem here is that `pd.DataFrame.apply` eventually uses the dtype of `df.values`, which in your case, will return a `numpy.ndarray` of dtype `object`, so it's never in your dtypes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have your list of allowed types, just use `loc`

```
allowed_types = [np.float64, np.float32,np.int32, np.int64]
mask = df.dtypes.isin(allowed_types)
df.loc[:, mask].sum()
```

However, a probably better approach is to use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html), using `np.number` as parent dtype if you want to select only columns that are numbers.

```
df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
```

Of course, can change `[np.number]` to your list of `allowed_types` if you really need to be specific.

Comment: Thanks! Alas, I really need those NaN values to be part of the result, so I can append them to the result of df.describe(). I have amended my original post with a section titled "motivation" that goes into detail about that.

Comment: Oh hey! It looks like I *can* use this, because I can append data frames with different column names. Yippee!